# Scheduling the JDBC consumer job in Stream Sets

Tags: hadoop, cloudera, streamsets

I need to schedule the JDBC consumer job to run everyday morning at 5 am, as far as I know, I can make the job run at 5 am when I start the job at 5 am and put 24 hours in the query interval.

But I need to schedule the first instance to start at 5 am without starting it manually (i'm lazy to wake up at 5 am :P) Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: Why not use Oozie?

Comment: how can I run the stremsets pipeline in oozie ??

Comment: I doubt you can. My question is if you have to schedule something, I think Oozie (or Nifi) support those features. I've not used Steamsets enough. But you tagged your question with Cloudera, so use Hue to build your Oozie workflow

Comment: I know about the oozie jobs, but this is different thing i'm trying to schedule stream sets pipeline through the Stream sets UI

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(Copying [my answer from Ask StreamSets](https://ask.streamsets.com/question/586/scheduling-the-jdbc-consumer-job/?answer=591#post-id-591))

There is no built-in scheduler in SDC, but you could use cron and the [StreamSets CLI](https://streamsets.com/documentation/datacollector/latest/help/index.html#Administration/Administration_title.html#concept_ywx_d5x_pt) to start the pipeline.